# Measurable set.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $\mathcal{A}$ a $\sigma$-algebra, and let $f,g\colon X\to [-\infty,+\infty]$ be a function. Let $\mathcal{M}(X,\mathcal{A})$ the family of the measurable function. I must prove that

> **Theorem.** Let $f,g\in\mathcal{M}(X,\mathcal{A})$. Then
>
> $(i)\;\{f<g\}\in\mathcal{A}$;
>
> $(ii)\;\{f\le g\}\in\mathcal{A}$;
>
> $(iii)\;\{f=g\}\in\mathcal{A}.$

**Proof.**$\;(i)$ We observe that $$\{f<g\}=\{f<g\;|\; g<+\infty\}\cup\{g=+\infty\}.$$ We note that $$\{g=+\infty\}=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\{g\ge n\}\in\mathcal{A}.$$ If $f(x),g(x)\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)<g(x)$ eists $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $f(x)<q<g(x)$, therefore $$\{f<g\;|\; g<+\infty\}=\bigcup_{q\in\mathbb{Q}}\big(\{f<q\}\cap\{q<g\}\big)\in\mathcal{A}.$$ Then $\{f<g\}\in\mathcal{A}.$

> **Quesion 1.** It's correct?

$(ii)\;$ We have to prove that $\complement\{g<f\}=\{f\le g\}.$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\complement\{g<f\}=&\complement\{g<f\;|\; f<+\infty\}\cap\complement\{f=+\infty\}\\
=&\{f\le g\;|\;f<+\infty\}\cap\{f<+\infty\}\qquad(1)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

> **Question 2.** How can I proceed from $(1)$ to prove that $\complement\{g<f\}=\{f\le g\}?$

Thanks!

Comment: i) is correct. By definition the complement of $(g<f)$ is $(f\leq g)$. For iii) write $f=g$ as intersection of $(f\leq g)$ and $(g\leq f)$

Comment: i) isn't correct, it may happen that $f(x)=g(x)=\infty$, so $\{g = \infty\}$ is not included in $\{f < g\}$.

Comment: @A.Bailleul If $f(x)=g(x)=\infty$, then $x\notin\{f<g\}$

Comment: Yes, and therefore $\{f<g\}$ is not equal to $\{f<g\;|\; g<+\infty\}\cup\{g=+\infty\}$ because $\{g=+\infty\}$ may not be included in $\{f<g\}$.

Comment: @A.Bailleul I do not understand why it is not correct. If $f(x)=g(x)=\infty$, then $x\in\{g=\infty\}$ and $x\notin\{f<g\;|\;g<\infty\}$, therefore $x\in\{f<g\;|\;g<\infty\}\cup\{g=\infty\}$, then $x\in\{f<g\}$

Comment: If $f(x)=g(x)=\infty$ then $x \not \in \{f < g\}$ right ? But $x \in \{g = \infty\} \subset \{f<g\;|\;g<\infty\}\cup\{g=\infty\}$, so $\{f < g\}$ cannot be equal to $\{f<g\;|\;g<\infty\}\cup\{g=\infty\}$.

Comment: You could use that $f-g$ is also a measurable function (using some good convention to deal with \infty-\infty) since $\mathcal{M}(X,\mathcal{A})$ is a vector space. Thus the first set is $\{f-g<0\}$, the second set is $\{f-g\leq 0\}=\{f-g>0\}^C$ and the third set is $\{f-g = 0\}=(\{f-g<0\}\cup\{f-g>0\})^C$.

Comment: @A. Bailleul So it's better to start from: $$\{f \le g\}=\{f\le g\;|\; g<+\infty\}\cup\{g=+\infty\}$$ In this way, however, I can not apply the density of the rationals.

Comment: You just need to change $\{g=\infty\}$ by $\{g= \infty\} \cap \{f < \infty\}$.

Comment: @A.Bailleul Thanks!